# Solution for differential equation describing linear input and exponential decay

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, mathematical-modeling

I try to model the concentration over time when there's an linear input and an exponential output (i.e. exponential decay) with known half-life.

```
Input(t) = a+b*t
```

, where `t` is the time (in years), `a` the input at year 0 and `b` the yearly growth to that input.

```
Output(t) = lambda*N(t)
```

, where `t` is the time (in years), `lambda` the exponential decay constant and `N(t)` the concentration at year `t`.

lambda is defined as

```
lambda = ln(2)/th
```

, where `th` is the half-life in years.

The differential equation is therefore:

```
dN/dt = Input - Output = a+b*t-lambda*N(t)
```

Using wolframAlpha I get this solution:

```
N(t) = C*exp(-lambda*t) + (b/lambda)*t + (a/lambda) - (b/lambda^2)
```

, where `C` is the initial concentration at `t=0`.

For small values of `th` this makes sense, but if `th` assumes higher values, the concentration is negative. How can this be?

As example:

```
a = 300
b = 20
th = 2 
C = 300
```

For `t = 10` I get a concentration of 1285.561.
But if I set `th` to 200, I get -1520536 at `t = 10`

Comment: Your input is quadratic, not linear. Linear input would add the same amount each year, so the total amount input increases linearly with respect to time. What you are doing is increasing the amount you are adding each year. Because the rate of increase in the yearly input is constant, the total amount input increases quadratically with respect to time. This doesn't explain your problem, but I suspect it means you set up the equation wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assumed that $C$ was the initial amount ("concentration" is a term indicating the ratio of "active" amount to total amount, which is not something so easily controlled). But this is not the case. The initial amount is $N(0)$, and that value is $$N(0) = C + \frac a\lambda - \frac b{\lambda^2}$$

When $a = 300, b = 20, C = 300$ and the half-life is $200$ years, that value is about
$-1578233.5$. The reason that after 10 years you have a negative amount is that you started with an even more negative amount and have not yet managed to overcome it.

If you want an initial amount $N(0)$ to be $300$, then you need to set $C = 300 - \frac a\lambda + \frac b{\lambda^2} \approx 1578833.5$

---

However, as I indicated in a comment, I am doubtful this equation is modelling what you think it is.

By your description, the repository starts out with an amount of $300$. The first year, an additional $300$ are added to it, for a total of $600$, not including decay. The next year, an additional $320$ are added, the year after $340$ are added, then $360$ the year after that, etc. Since you described it as "linear", I don't think this is what you are after.

Instead, I am guessing that $a$ is supposed to be the initial amount, and each year an additional amount $b$ is added. This gives the differential equation
$$\frac {dN}{dt} = b -\lambda N$$ whose solution is
$$N(t) = \frac b{\lambda} + Ce^{-\lambda t}$$
Since $a = N(0) = b/\lambda + C$, we have $C = a - b/\lambda$. Therefore

$$N(t) = \frac b{\lambda} + \left(a - \frac b\lambda\right)e^{-\lambda t}$$

Is the equation you are after.

Comment: Thanks for that! Indeed I wanted to model a constantly increasing input. Your remarks to C helped a lot.